# number of lessons for a teacher SQL

Tags: postgresql

I have four tables, one is teacher and 3 different kinds of lessons.

My task is to find the teacher that has given the most lessons during a year.

input:

```
 lesson1.id   lesson1.date    teacher.id  
      1        2020-12-01         1 
      2        2020-04-01         1

 lesson2.id lesson2.date teacher.id 
      1      2020-10-01       2
      2      2020-05-01       3  

lesson3.id lesson3.date teacher.id 
      1      2020-02-01       1
      2      2020-06-01       3 

teacher.id  teacher.name 
      1        john    
      2        scott        
      3        david
```

output:

```
teacher.id    teacher.name   lessons_given
    1              john             3
```

I tried to join them together with left join on teacher but its not working...
Hope you guys can help me out:)
Thanks

Comment: Try union the tables in your query. It would be easier if you have 1 table for lessons instead of 3.  (with a extra lessontype column)

Answer (score 1):

What you are attempting to build is a many-to-many (m:m) between Teacher and Lesson. Instead what you have is many one-to-many relationships. While that works for a small number of lessons (with some difficulty) think about the same requirement with with 50 or 500 or more lessons. What you actually need is 3 tables:

```
create table lessons( lesson_id integer generated always as identity 
                    , name      text 
                    , subject   text  -- for example
                    -- other lesson related attributes
                    ); 
create table teachers( teacher_id integer generated always as identity
                     , name   text 
                     -- other related teacher attributes
                     );
create table teacher_lessons( teacher_id  integer
                            , lesson_id   integer 
                            , lesson_date date
                            ):
```

Now you have a structure that can handle any number of either teachers and/or lessons. And are further are available other uses as is,  say perhaps students to lessons.  See [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=e59af49324d94e5c5ad98a78bb3ce86a) for current issue.

Answer (score 0):

You could `union all` the three lesson tables to get a "flat" list of lessons, and then join that on the teachers table:

```sql
SELECT t.id, t.name, COUNT(*)
FROM   teacher t
JOIN   (SELECT teacher_id FROM lesson1 UNION ALL
        SELECT teacher_id FROM lesson2 UNION ALL
        SELECT teacher_id FROM lesson3) l ON t.id = l.teacher_id
```

Answer (score 0):

The obvious way to do is to use Belayer's solution.

However if **and only if** you can not put all the data in a single table for some reason (for example if lesson1, lesson2 and lesson3 all have specific attributes), then another solution would be to use table [inheritance](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-inherit.html).

For instance :

```
CREATE TABLE lesson (
  id INT,
  date TIMESTAMP,
  teacher INT
);

ALTER TABLE lesson1 INHERIT lesson;
ALTER TABLE lesson2 INHERIT lesson;
ALTER TABLE lesson3 INHERIT lesson;
```

Now, in order to count the number of lessons each teacher is involved into, you can just use the lesson table:

```
SELECT teacher.id, teacher.name, COUNT(lesson.id)
FROM teacher
LEFT JOIN lesson ON lesson.teacher = teacher.id
GROUP BY teacher
ORDER BY COUNT(lesson.id) DESC
FETCH FIRST ROW WITH TIES;
```

You can replace the last line with `LIMIT 1` if you are only interested in getting one of the most active teachers, but then your result is no longer deterministic.

Again, please do not use inheritance if there is no need to.